# Keystone.js cloudinary image multiple transformations

Tags: node.js, cloudinary, keystonejs

How can I upload full image and create thumbnail for it using Keystone.js CloudinaryImage field Type. Sometimes I need to have one image in multiple versions (transformations), e.g:

- fullsize
- thumbnail
- b&w thumbnail

What approach should I take?

Comment: In Node.js you can use Sharp module https://github.com/lovell/sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, you should take a look at the Keystone's demo: https://github.com/JedWatson/keystone-demo
Which uses Cloudinary for displaying images.

Specifically, see: https://github.com/JedWatson/keystone-demo/blob/287df31ff30d3784d109d21d73f0dee73a31698e/templates/views/gallery.jade#L25
Where an image is being limit cropped and displayed.

Comment: After some further reading and testing I've grasped cloudinary concept of managing images. You upload source image without any transformations, and you transform it ad-hoc whenever you want secific transformations.
What is important - cloudinary accounts only first transformation. Following transformations of the same type, done on the same image are cached.